# Kotlin: How to make toolbar menu with Anko DSL?

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, toolbar, anko

How to make Android toolbar menu with Anko DSL directly in UI class?
Do not want to write listeners in my Activity class.

Regarding my answer given below, is there a way to avoid XML recource file to describe menu items?

Answer (score 4):

Anko doesn't have any helpers for menu building yet. But there is an [open Pull Request](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/pull/324) for that.

Until that, you can use standard Kotlin/Android tools to create menu items in your code quite easily:

```
class ActivityMainUi: AnkoComponent<ActivityMain> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ActivityMain>) = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            appBarLayout {
                lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                toolbar {
                    lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                    menu.apply {
                        add("Action1").apply {
                            tooltipText = "Start Action 1"

                            // Unfortunately you cant't use `icon = R.drawable.ic_action_foo` here,
                            // because it would expect a Drawable instead of a Resource ID
                            setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_foo)

                            setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                                startActivity<Activity1>()
                                true
                            }
                        }

                        add("Action2")
                                // If you don't like the extra apply,
                                // you can also use chain most of the setters
                                .setTooltipText("Start Action 2")
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_bar)
                                .setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                                    startActivity<Activity2>()
                                    true
                                }
                                // Not all types of menu Icons do actually show the icon,
                                // so make it an Action for demo purposes
                                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS) // <-- this is actually one of the setters, that cant be chained
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's about what I wanted. I'll wait a few days to see if anybody else posts a solution, but I believe the bounty is yours

Comment: How would I add an Icon for that menu, and that kind of configuration?

Comment: Updated the code sample to include some more properties (incl. Icons)

Comment: Any idea how to use this with a table layout? `appBarLayout` doesn't seem to work there. Using just `toolbar` places the toolbar underneath the actual application bar...

Comment: Is there a way to make a group of items pragmatically? I can't seem to find a java function for creating Groups. Every example I can find uses XML.

Comment: @Duane Sorry, but what kind of groups do you mean exactly? Can you provide a link to the XML examples you mentioned?

Comment: In XML, a menu item can be a child of a <group>. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Answer (score 0):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file select the theme without ActionBar

Create your menu XML resource file as usual:

```
<menu ...>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    android:title="Action1"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action2"
    android:title="Action2"/>
</menu>
```

For each item in menu create your custom activites

Create the main activity class:

```
class ActivityMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       ActivityMainUI().setContentView(this)

       //do not use setActionBar() or setSupportActionBar()
    }

    // do not override onOptionsItemSelected() and onCreateOptionsMenu() here

 }


class ActivityMainUi: AnkoComponent<ActivityMain> {

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ActivityMain>) = with(ui) {

        coordinatorLayout {

            // justify layout

            appBarLayout {

                toolbar {

                    // justify your toolbar

                    inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu_xml_resource)

                    onMenuItemClick { item ->
                        when (item!!.itemId) {
                            R.id.action_1 -> {
                                startActivity<Activity1>()
                                true
                            }
                            R.id.action_2 -> {
                                startActivity<Activity2>()
                                true
                            }
                            else -> false
                        }
                    }

                }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

            // put other views
        }

    }

}
```